# Views PDF pagination

Tags: views, 7

Is it possible to add a pagination to a pdf when using views pdf module in drupal 7. Or is there any custom module.

Comment: By pagination do you mean numbering at the bottom of each page of the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf. Just make the view page as any other view.

Comment: In views pdf there is an option for PDF template settings and CSS attachment. does the PDF template need to be a PHP template and I have attached CSS and it does not seem to have an effect?